# Download Image Using Alamofire and Save to Application Support on Mac

Tags: cocoa, swift, nsfilemanager, alamofire

The Alamofire readme indicates that you can download and save a file like this:

```
let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)

Alamofire.download(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/stream/100", destination: destination)
```

...but I want to change the location where it is saved. How do I alter `.DocumentDirectory` to be my app's `Application Support` path on Mac OS X?

I can generate my app's local `NSURL` path like this:

```
let path = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.ApplicationSupportDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as NSURL
let newPath = path.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MyApp/user-profile.png")
```

I'm unclear on how to use this with Alamofire's `suggestedDownloadDestination`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suggestedDownloadDestination will try to find an available directory, but in your case you already know the full path so you don't need it.

Just create a closure with your path:

```
let path = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.ApplicationSupportDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as NSURL
let newPath = path.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MyApp/user-profile.png")
Alamofire.download(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/stream/100", { _ in newPath })
```

Comment: Ah, brilliant! Thanks a ton for your help. This worked, though I had to remove `destination:` since Xcode threw a warning about an extraneous parameter: 

`Alamofire.download(.GET, imgPath, { _ in newPath })`